# Developing two android apps and communicating between two

Tags: android, communication

I am developing two applications names **A** and **B**.

**Application A** as activity named `MainActivity`, service called `UpdateService`, `BroadcastReciever` called `UpdateReceiver`.

**Application B** as activity named `TestActivity`, service called `DoService`, `BroadcastReciever` called `DoReceiver`.

In my **application B**, I want to access few methods and code from `MainActivity` which is in **Application A**.

In this way, I need full control of **Application A** code to access it in my **application B**.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot directly access methods of `Activity` in different app.

`Broadcast` would work but if you want more control (i.e. invoke remote methods) consider binding to a remote service in the other app or use `Messenger` and handler to communicate.

Here is a short tutorial on [inter-app communication](https://web.archive.org/web/20130731024012/http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/InterAppCommunication)

Comment: @iTech The inter-app communication tutorial link seems to be broken, I get a Not Found, any ideas?

Comment: Interesting!! I came here after a long time it was posted the link in the answer is working with [WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130731024012/http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/InterAppCommunication)

Comment: Be aware that if your app targets API level 26 or greater, implicit broadcasts will not work with the exception of a handful of system broadcasts. Your own broadcast will not get past process boundaries unless they are "explicit"

Answer (score 5):

You can't share methods and code segments between different applications, but you can use intents to send data bundles back and forth, check this similar question:

[android communication between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638939/android-communication-between-two-applications)