# Observer pattern in Android that crosses process boundries

Tags: android

Scenario: App B registers for a listener with App A. Upon some event, App A notifies App B. (both A and B are Android apps, each gets it's own process when started)

This may be possible with Async AIDL.  But B has to bind to A on boot-on/complete. Is there a better approach than AIDL binder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302093/developing-two-android-apps-and-communicating-between-two

Comment: see `ContentResolver#registerContentObserver`, also you dont need AIDL for it to work,you can use std Binder mechanism when binding to a service