# Find and press button in different application (ANDROID)

Tags: android

I start a different application from my application and I want to find and press the button in that application. Is it possible? (Provided I have all the access and source code of the application). If yes, can provide any full reference or code with detail?

Comment: You cant press button in application from different application. But you can call the method by using broadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

You could have just searched `communication between android applications` and you would have found many results.

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302093/developing-two-android-apps-and-communicating-between-two) one, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638939/android-communication-between-two-applications) one.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found the keyword needed. I need it to be done using intent instead of broadcast.

Comment: @MAINAMEKC What do you mean ? When do you need to use `Intent` ?

Comment: ya I need to use Intent

Comment: @MAINAMEKC If you don't answer the questions of my previous comment I cannot help you

Comment: @MAINAMEKC Any news ?

Comment: I need to access to target application's element through root provided I have all the target application's element and it is in same device, it is some kind of hacking I think? Sorry, I'm really new to android with little basis.

Comment: What is *through root*? Did you check the links I gave you? Also, you did not answer my question in my previous comment.