# Send data from one xamarin.android app to another xamarin.forms app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

is there any way to send data from one xamarin.forms app to another xamarin.forms app. Android application the goal is only for android, while the other application is android and ios. The android application has to send data locally to android application / ios but the android application is receiving it. in my aplication android i cant open another app and send data. but i cant receveing data in my aplication. this is the code in android aplication:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.companyname.Opiniao","android.intent.action.B"));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editTextEmail.getText() + "\n " + editTextPassword.getText());
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing two android apps and communicating between two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302093/developing-two-android-apps-and-communicating-between-two)

Comment: with android app, i cant send data and open aplication. but i dont find in xamarin.forms receveing data from android app.

Comment: Please don't post your code in comments, update your question instead.

Comment: sorry. I did not know

Comment: Xamarin.forms just a c# wrapper for Android and Ios, so you need do it on each platform.

Comment: I just want to pass data to my xamarin.forms.android, is there no way for it to receive the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've already been able to solve the problem.

In my Android Aplication, i use this code:

```
    void enviar(){
    // Usa o nome do package que nos queremos encontrar
    boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.companyname.Opiniao");

    if(isAppInstalled) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.companyname.Opiniao","android.intent.action.B"));
        intent.putExtra("Dados", editTextEmail.getText() + "\n" + editTextPassword.getText());
        startActivity(intent);


    } else {
        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

//Procura o package, se tiver instalado, envia um true, se não encontrar devolve um false
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

in my xamarin.forms, in android mainActivity, i put this:

```
        async void Receber()
    {
        text = Intent.GetStringExtra("Dados");
        string dados = "Dados";
        bool result;
        result = await dados.WriteTextAllAsync(text);
     }
```

Comment: FYI: `await dados.WriteTextAllAsync(text);`, where `dados` is type `string`, does not match any documentation that I find. Doc suggests `await File.WriteTextAllAsync(path, text);`, where `string path` is file path.