# How to message between completely different android apps?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, chat

I want to send a text-message from a bluetooth-app to a chat-app. I have access to the source code of both.

How do I do that? I could merge them, but want to avoid that...

The forground running chat-app is Linphone.

The background "sending" app is the bluetooth terminal, perhaps running as a service.

Q: Are intents public somehow so other apps can get to them like I want??

```
Sender:    https://github.com/cellurl3/Bluetooth-Terminal

Receiver: https://github.com/cellurl3/linphone-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/org/linphone/chat
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Developing two android apps and communicating between two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302093/developing-two-android-apps-and-communicating-between-two)

Comment: i guess so.  Doesn't look like a very popular avenue of development.. Thanks Ryan