# How to send data from 1 app to another in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have 2 app, A and B, and i want send 2+2 from application A to B and in return i want to receive 4 from App B, please tell me the process and full code base.

Comment: something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302093/developing-two-android-apps-and-communicating-between-two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.From app A Trigger a broadCast1 with both of your numbers.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.myapps.appA");
intent.putExtra("num1",2);
intent.putExtra("num2",2);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

2. now register the receiver for broadCast1 in App B, you can do this in onCreate of its Main activity.

   private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver1;

...

```
broadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver1, new 
                             IntentFilter("com.myapps.appA");
```

3. Inside onRecieve get both the numbers  from the intent and Trigger another broadCast with the result i.e.

   ```
   int num1 = intent.getIntExtra("num1",0);
   int num2 = intent.getIntExtra("num2",0);

   Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.myapps.appB");
   intent2.putExtra("sum",num1+num2);
   YourActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent2);
   ```
4. Now Register the reciever for Broadcast2 Inside your App A, you can do this in onCreate of its Main activity.

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver2;

...

```
broadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver2, new 
                            IntentFilter("com.myapps.appB");
```

5. Inside its OnRecive() get the result

   int sum = intent.getIntExtra("sum",0);
6. Most importantly don't forget to unregister the receivers in onStop on the activity