# how to open Native own android app from ionic hybrid app with passing parameter

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Open own native android app from ionic Hybrid app  with passing parameter to native app and after process done from native app need to get back to hybrid app with success or fail what ever process status.

Comment: Its duplicate question as below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302093/developing-two-android-apps-and-communicating-between-two

Comment: No , That why i mention Hybrid app ,Not 2 native app.One is native app and one is ionic hybrid app.