# Android exposing service to other applications

Tags: android, ipc, rpc

I need to expose a service in one android application. This service is to be used by other Android applications downloaded from play store in the device. How do I do it ?

Tried using AIDL, but it works only interprocess communication within the single application. Got error  when importing the service.

It also worked when including application that contained the service as a library. But I want to do without making it a library.

Faced errors in importing when using methods mentioned here.. which works when they are in same application.
[android communication between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638939/android-communication-between-two-applications)

I also do not want to use content resolver.

Comment: i think you should read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: what is the use case of your service ? what do you intend to allow other applications to do with your service ?

Comment: My application should expose a service which can be consumed by other applications, like blue tooth service..