# Ad mobs blocking function

Tags: android, google-api, admob

I have created multiple applications using Google admob feature,they all are showing ads ,now I wish to create a new application to block all these ads from all the other applications.I would really very helpful , if anyone can suggested the approach to do so,thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have several applications with advertising. Do you want an application that will disable it in them?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the flag "Display ad", which you can turn off on the basis of the recommendations in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4639166/2413972).