# View a jpeg image sent via intent in an android application

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two android applications created via android studio. From application1, I try to send a picture to application2 and view it.

For this, from app1 one I passed the image via intent to application2 as follows:

```
Intent imgIntent = new Intent();
imgIntent .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri uriToImage = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.appname/" + R.drawable.pic_png);
    imgIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
    imgIntent .setType("image/*");//image/jpeg
    startActivityForResult(imgIntent , REQUEST_CODE);
```

How can I view the image sent via intent in application2 ?
If we send a text, we can get it as:

`getIntent().getExtras().getString("textvalue");`

I am a newbie in android platform. Please help me.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check [this](http://infobloggall.com/2015/04/14/communication-between-two-applications-in-android-using-messenger) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4639166/3967525)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri stream=(Uri)getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Then, pass that `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library, like Picasso.