# Is it possible that one application uses *.so module that was shipped with another application?

Tags: android

I've got an application written in Android Studio, which includes some external modules with *.so extension under jniLibs folder. The question is: can I use those modules from second application from totally different package if both applications are installed on the same device?

Comment: You might want to explain why you can't include the modules separately for both apps. Note that normally you would go through Android APIs to communicate between apps. See: [android communication between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4639166/295004)

Comment: It's not that I can't include the modules, it's rather theoretical question. Let's assume that I've got an application and the second application is closed source, but I know that it is shipped with some *.so modules. Can I use them from my app?